# Access VBA Loop with Dcount Condition

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
rcount = DCount("F1", "T1")

Do While rcount > 0

DoCmd.OpenQuery "q1"

Loop
```

Can anyone tell me while this code won't work?  It loops through, but seemingly ignores the condition of `rcount > 0`

Comment: After you first set the value of `rcount`, it never changes.  So if the condition, `rcount > 0`, is `True` when you hit `Do While`, it will remain `True`.  Please describe what you want to accomplish.

Comment: If the code is looping then it isn't ignoring the condition... have you tried running this with the Locals window open to see what the actual value of `rcount` is at this point?

Comment: Sorry, I left that part out.  The table the dcount is against is being modified every loop by deleting 1 record at a time until the dcount = 0 at which point the loop should stop.  If I break the loop and look at the table the dcount is against, I see that my code has deleted all records in which case the dcount should be 0.

Comment: Try copying the `rcount =` line right before the `Loop` line?  That way it sets a value to `rcount` before the loop and within the loop.

Comment: Chrismas007,  thank you as well, that was pretty much what Hansup said.  Kudos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the value of *rcount* after you execute the delete query.

```vb
rcount = DCount("F1", "T1")

Do While rcount > 0
    'DoCmd.OpenQuery "q1"
    CurrentDb.Execute "q1", dbFailOnError
    rcount = DCount("F1", "T1")
Loop
```

Note by using `CurrentDb.Execute` instead of `DoCmd.OpenQuery`, you can avoid the confirmation messages without turning `SetWarnings` off.  And it also allows you to use *dbFailOnError* which will notify you about problems which would otherwise fail silently.

However I don't understand why you want to delete all the *T1* records one at a time when you could remove them all at one go ...

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE FROM T1;", dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!  To answer you question - It's because I'm doing some ridiculous unconventional table manipulation for someone in a position I can't dispute with and the way I'm doing it requires me to delete 1 at a time.  (basically using another query to determine top1 record).  I'm sure we've all been there. :)